# InvalidOperationException: Can not find compilation library location for package 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery'

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Хочу просто попробовать впервые запустить проект.

dotnet info:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Файл csproj:

```
<Project ToolsVersion="15.0" Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework><netcoreapp2 class="2"></netcoreapp2></TargetFramework>
    <PreserveCompilationContext>true</PreserveCompilationContext>
    <CopyRefAssembliesToPublishDirectory>false</CopyRefAssembliesToPublishDirectory>
    <RuntimeFrameworkVersion>2.2</RuntimeFrameworkVersion>
    <MvcRazorExcludeRefAssembliesFromPublish>false</MvcRazorExcludeRefAssembliesFromPublish>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore" Version="1.0.4" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc" Version="1.0.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles" Version="1.0.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug" Version="1.0.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink" Version="1.0.1" />
  </ItemGroup>


</Project>
```

И вот сама ошибка:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Использовался Yeoman для генерации проекта.
Если нужна дополнительная информация, пожалуйста, напишите.

Comment: Пожалуйста, приведите, код текстом, а не скриншотом. Это позволит воспроизвести ошибку и помочь Вам с решением, а также проиндексировать страницу, что в будущем может помочь тем, кто столкнётся с таким же вопросом.

Comment: @nomnoms12, исправлено

Comment: <MvcRazorCompileOnPublish>false</MvcRazorCompileOnPublish> добавьте

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Вы проект запускает на asp.net core > 2, но пакеты версии 1.04 и подобное.

   Проставьте верные версии для пакетов(обычно они совпадают с версией asp.net core) или снизьте таргет до asp.net core 1.

   И не забудьте сделать dotnet restore
2. Впервые вижу определение TargetFramework элементом, а не значением. Попробуйте заменить на netcoreapp2.2
3. Проверьте так же установлен ли .net core 2.2(можете ли вы создать пустой проект asp.net core на платформе .net core 2.2?).

Comment: Проект нужно обязательно запустить на 2.2. Поменял версии пакетов на версию asp .net core(2.2.301) `<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore" Version="2.2.301" />` и тд. Вылезла ошибка сборки: **/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/2.2.301/NuGet.targets(121,5): error : Входные данные восстановления недопустимы. Целевая платформа "unsupported" недопустима.**

Comment: @DigitalResistance я также впервые вижу определение TargetFramework элементом, а не значением. Попробуйте заменить на <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.2</TargetFramework>

Comment: @DigitalResistance проверьте так же установлен ли .net core 2.2(можете ли вы создать пустой проект asp.net core на платформе .net core 2.2?).

Comment: спасибо, всё , что вы сказали помогло решению проблемы.

Comment: @DigitalResistance обновлю тогда сейчас ответ.